# Formatting a number with space instead of commas as thousand separator

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to display a number like 1000000 as 1 000 000 ?
I have tried using NumberFormat

```
var formatter = NumberFormat("#,###");
return Text("${formatter.format(price.toInt())}"); // 985000 returns 985,000
```

But i would like to have a space instead of the commas

**EDIT**

Solved by adding the method replaceAll

```
var formatter = NumberFormat('#,###');
return Text('${formatter.format(price.toInt())}'.replaceAll(',', ' '));
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Use a space instead of comma inside your formatter

Comment: it doesnt work, i get 985000 without space nor commas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var formatter = NumberFormat('#,###');
return Text('${formatter.format(price.toInt())}'.replaceAll(',', ' '));
```

Comment: Hats off for the idea

Comment: A word of caution: You should explicitly specify the `locale`: `NumberFormat('#,###', 'en_US')`. From `NumberFormat` dartdoc: _If the locale is not specified, it will default to the current locale._ If you don't specify the locale and the "current locale" happens to be one that does not use commas as thousand separator (which are many locales), the `replaceAll` in the form currently specified in the answer will not work.